# How to solve the integral $I(a,b) = \int_a^b 1-\frac{I(a,x)-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

While doing derivations for my work, I came upon an integral with a recurrence relation

$$
I(a,b) = \int_a^b \left[1-\frac{I(a,x)-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right]\,dx
$$

Is it possible to put $I(a,b)$ into an explicit form? If so, how?

Note: These constraints exist: $\alpha \leq a \leq b \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I(b)=\int_{a}^{b} 1-\frac{I(x)-\alpha}{1-\alpha} dx, I(a)=0$$
D.w.r. $b$ using lebnitz, we get
$$I'(b)=1-\frac{I(b)-\alpha}{1-\alpha} \implies I'(b)+\frac{1}{1-\alpha}I(b)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}.$$
This is a linear ODE whose integrating factor is $e^{b/(1-\alpha)}$.
So $$I(b)=e^{-b/(1-\alpha)} \int \frac{e^{b/(1-\alpha)}}{(1-\alpha)} db+Ce^{-b/(1-\alpha)}$$
$$\implies I(b)=1+Ce^{-b/(1-\alpha)}$$
Using $I(a)=0$, we get
$$C= -e^{a/(1-\alpha)}$$
Finally, $$I(a,b)=1-e^{(a-b)/(1-\alpha)}$$

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: differentiate w.r.t. $b$ and get a simple ODE. The solution is $I(a,b)=1−e^{(a−b)/(1−\alpha)}$.